# How to Perform for loop type of logic in Azure Data FLow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Here is my requirement:

Basically in a for loop there are 3 things: initialisation, condition, loop

So i have to generate a row basing on for loop logic for every row like:

- **initialisation** : `{Start_Rcvd Date}` (col in my table)
- **condition:** `DateBetweenDRO` (New Column) `<= {WIP AGE DATE}` (Col in my table)
- **loop:** `addDays({DateBetweenDRO},1)` (Col in my table)

Output: In the output, for every row it loops through the condition and generate a column and fills from initialsion value to loop ending condition.

Let us consider 2 date cols
NewDate : 31/01/2022
OldDate: 01/05/2022

Now I am mentioning :

**initialization expression : NewDate(31/01/2022)
conditional expression** : NewDate<=OldDate
**loop** : NewDate+1month

**Output can be :**
[image]

So For every row its generating 3 rows and adding 1 month every time as value in NewDate col.

Can you help please how to achieve this kind of thing in Azure dataflow

Comment: Azure Data Flows is not meant to be thought of as a substitute to a procedural language (which contain things like for loops). It is more akin to a replacement for an SQL View - a **declarative** syntax. The typical way to do something like what you're describing is via a cross-join, followed by a filter step, which DataFlows **can** do. As such, the way to ask for help here would simply be to give an example input table, and the corresponding output table you want to see after being processed. There is no direct way to capture the procedural logic you've described as a dataflow configuration.

Comment: Data flow doesn't have loops, but we can modify the columns according to our requirements by using transformations like filter option, provide some sample data like input and output will help you to get the solution.

Comment: Added additional info please help

Comment: Still your requirements are not clear. 
1) **For every row its generating 3 rows** -- Your sample data generates 4 rows for 1 row.   
2) Is it sufficient to add +1 to the month or add 30 days? Could you clearly mention this?

Comment: Yes 1 month must be added in the new column and other col data must be same .

Comment: Can refer https://youtu.be/Srlu7YonH-8

Comment: My project is Alteryx to Adf . SO i need alternative for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to Perform for loop type of logic in Azure Data FLow
> I tried to repro this scene in Azure data flow and below is the approach.

- An initial value for **new_date** field is assigned in a dataflow parameter
  `initialnewParameter="2022-01-05"`.

[image]

- Source data is taken as in below image.
  [image]
- In order to generate multiple rows, first total number of months between old date and new date is computed.
  `toInteger(round(monthsBetween(old_date,toDate($initialnewParameter)),0,1))`. This will give the rounded-up value of months between old and new date.
- [Maploop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#maploop) function is used to create an array starting from 1 to value of months between old and new date.
- In derived column transformation column named **monthsbw[]** is created and expression is given as `mapLoop(toInteger(round(monthsBetween(old_date,toDate($initialnewParameter)),0,1)),#index)`.

[image]

- monthsbw[] is created and values are from 1 to months between old and new date as in below image.
  [image]
- **Flatten transform** is used and this data is unrolled by **monthsbw** array.
  [image]
- Output of the flattened data
  [image]
- Derived column transformation is taken and monthbw is added to the dataflow parameter `initialnewParameter`  which stores the initial value of new date.
  **Expression for new_date column:**
  `addMonths(toDate($initialnewParameter),toInteger(monthbw)-1)`

[image]

- Output of the derived column activity:
  [image]
- By this way, you can generate multiple rows from a row in azure data flow. You can use select transformation and select only required columns.

Comment: FOllowing this methid ,if there is a differece of 1000 months between two dates ,its failing to generate array ,saying array size exceeded. Is there any other method because here array size is limited

Comment: Could you ask a new question on this and share what you tried in the question? That will help SO forum members to assist you.